# how can I make a favicon in html

Tags: html, css

How do I make this image my favicon? https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5DAs.jpg

I've tried looking this up on other websites, and I couldn't find anything that worked well. Please just provide me with some code that I can insert into the header parameter, as that would be easiest for me to learn from.

Comment: [http://www.favicon.cc/](http://www.favicon.cc/)

Comment: wow, did you even try to research your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Major Browsers:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.example.com/image.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://www.example.com/image.gif">
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://www.example.com/image.ico">`</pre>
```

Internet Explorer 7 & Below:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/image.ico" />
<link rel="address bar icon" href="http://www.example.com/image.ico">
```

Cross Browser Approach:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.example.com/image.png">
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/alternateimage.ico"/><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<link rel="icon" 
  type="image/png" 
  href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```